# Is DOM ready instantly after appending new elements heavily via jquery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

First thing, I am new to JS. So I have a sample JS here.

```
<script>
    function main(){
      code_that_add_contents_to_dom();
      code_that_works_on_added_contents_on_dom();
    }
</script>
```

I've been working on a web project where above situation is usually encountered. Let us suppose the following functions.

```
var code_that_add_contents_to_dom = function(){
  var parent = document.getElementById("id_1");
  var child = document.createElement('div');
  child.id = 'child_id_1';
  parent.appendChild(child);
  ...
}
```

The above function adds new elements to dom and suppose there is lots of appendChild Statements.
Now lets create a function that works on the very elements that were appended to DOM by the function above. For example, let us suppose we're creating a dataTable in that very element.

```
var code_that_works_on_added_contents_on_dom = function(){
   var dataTable = $('#child_id_1').dataTable(); // or something similar that 
                                                 // works on previously added                        
                                                 //elements
}
```

Now let us suppose that I called function main(). The problem is that the second function either generates error or does nothing at all. But if i write the main function as below:

```
<script>
        function main(){
          code_that_add_contents_to_dom();
          setTimeout(function(){
              code_that_works_on_added_contents_on_dom();
          },some_millisecs);
        }
 </script>
```

If some_millisecs has some value say 500 for example (in my particular case), then everything works fine.
So here are the questions.

1. Does the DOM manipulation methods takes up time to actually make
   changes to DOM even after the manipulation method has returned?
2. What is the best practice that I can follow to make things work in this case?
3. Or am I missing something that is dead simple?

**EDIT**
I've been getting answers of returning and using references from the function that manipulates DOM. I want make it clear that its its not always the case. Suppose I wan't to create a dataTable(Bootstrap) from JSON file. In function `code_that_add_contents_to_dom();`I parse JSON and create the markup dynamically as

```
<table id='example'>
 <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
            </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Roxi</td>
                <td>System Admin</td>
            </tr>

</tbody>

</table>
```

Now the second function `code_that_works_on_added_contents_on_dom();`initializes data table to the example div.

Now I face the similar problem, as the table markup is being generated dynamically, the second function initializes the dataTable but says "no data found". But it works with setTimeOut added to initialize data table after certain delay.

I actually have workaround this by using dataTable.addRow() method. But what I want to know is, why isn't DOM ready as soon as the DOM manipulation function returns? I hope I made myself clear

Thanks again!!

Comment: `document.createElement('<div>');` you're supposed to pass just `div`

Comment: Create two functions and call the `make_changes()` function at the end of the `add_changes()` function is one way of doing it - however, we cannot be 100% sure until we know what changes you are making

Comment: sorry my mistake, m gonna make an edit ..thanks for pointing. Just typo ;)

Comment: @DarrenSweeney...I've tried that way...still no success :(

Comment: Can you create a minimal repro of the actual issue you're seeing.  What you're trying [should work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/j33cgbzo/1/), even with the combination of using vanilla JS to create/append the element and jQuery to manipulate it.

Comment: My entire team are facing similar issue...so I thought there was some issue.. @JamesThorpe I'll try to create a repo

Comment: Are you sure that the exact jquery function is not dependent on some other structure on your page?

Comment: The way you describe it there actually shouldn't be any problem with your code if the DOM is ready when you invoke `main()`. Is it?

Comment: Also, to be on the safe side, please check if your doctype is OK. jQuery doesn't support quirks mode, and all sorts of weird things tend to happen if there is a typo in the doctype. (I'd be surprised if it played a role here, but still, I suggest you have a quick look.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `code_that_works_on_added_contents_on_dom` look for references of the elements you just created, you can use the references you already get, when creating them.

Aside 1: it's confusing that you mix pure DOM functions (`document.getElementById("child_id_1")`) and jQuery (`$('#child_id_1')`). It would make everything more readable and easier if you would choose one method and stand by it.

Aside 2: In `code_that_add_contents_to_dom` you look for an element with the ID `child_id_1`, but assign the same ID to the new element you create. I assume that is an error in the example code. However you use `child.ID`, which is wrong anyway, it should be `child.id`. Also using my method you don't need to assign IDs anyway, because you'll be using the existing references.

Example:

```
<script>
    function main(){
      var createdElements = code_that_add_contents_to_dom();
      code_that_works_on_added_contents_on_dom(createdElements.elementA, createdElements.elementB);
    }

var code_that_add_contents_to_dom = function(){
  var parent = $("#child_id_1"); // Use jQuery everywhere
  var child = $("<div>");
  parent.appendChild(child);
  return {
    elementA: parent,
    elementB: child
  };
}  

code_that_works_on_added_contents_on_dom(parent, child) {
  child.dataTable();
}
</script>
```

Comment: @RoToRa...lets suppose that  my code is correct and it appends elements to dom. I like the way you suggested and will try it. Still, my question is why does my code behave differently and only works when used with setTimeout making me thing that DOM is not as good as ready as soon as the manipulation function returns?

Comment: @phoenix Are you maybe doing something asynchronously, e.g. loading the table data with AJAX?

Comment: I'm preety sure I'm not doing that. Only thing I've done is initializing the dataTable. And initializing works only when maintaining certain delay after the markup generation function returns.

Comment: @phoenix jquery DataTables can work with AJAX. You'll need to show a working example that demonstrates the problem. Try building a test case, for example on jsfiddle.com